# How do I print vertical text in C# that prints up? (StringFormat.DirectionVirtical prints down)

Tags: c#, text, system.drawing

I want to print text in C# using System.Drawing, but setting the StringFormat.DirectionVirtical flag only seems to print text downward. I want it to print the other way, like you see in graphs.

This will be for more than just forms, so I want to see if there is a way to do this without using a transformation matrix while drawing.

Is there any way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use Graphics.RotateTransform to get the text rotate the way you want.  For example:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form {
    public Form1() {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e) {
        string text = "Vertical text";
        SizeF textSize = e.Graphics.MeasureString(text, this.Font);
        e.Graphics.RotateTransform(-90);
        e.Graphics.DrawString(text, this.Font, Brushes.Black,
            new PointF(-textSize.Width, 0));
    }
}
```